# convert string to multidimensional array

Tags: php

I have this array

```
dev3->content->->mktg->->->pls1->->->pls2->->->config->->splash
```

I want to convert this string to multidimensional array. like this

```
 Array
        (
        [0] => dev3
        Array (
            [0] => ->content
            Array  (
                [0] => ->->mktg
                    Array(
                        [0] => ->->->pls1
                        [1] => ->->->pls2
                        [2] => ->->->config
                    )
                [1] => ->->splash
            )
        )
    )
```

Can anyone do this

Comment: Could we see the code you've tried to get this working?

Comment: sure, we are here to help you....

Comment: i cant find any solution, i have just string

Comment: you want values together with arrows into this new array?

Comment: do you need manually or pragmatically???

Comment: the presented output is incorrect

Comment: ofcouce programatically

Comment: can you explain the out put. Why are they nested the way they are, I guess its the number of -> before the words?

Comment: quite impossible, but not impossible.

Comment: because that is the directory structure

Comment: you need something called regular expression here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it does not work if level will be increaed more then +1 on any step

```
$str = 'dev3->content->->mktg->->->pls1->->->pls2->->->config->->splash';

$in = preg_split('/(?<!>)(?=->)/', $str);
```

Above we make such array from the input string

```
Array
(
    [0] => dev3
    [1] => ->content
    [2] => ->->mktg
    [3] => ->->->pls1
    [4] => ->->->pls2
    [5] => ->->->config
    [6] => ->->splash
)
```

continue working

```
$result = [];
$p = &$result;
$level = 0;
foreach($in as $i) {
  // Count next level
  $c = substr_count($i, '->');
  // if level is not changed
  if($c == $level) { $p[] = $i; continue;  } 
  // level increased
  if ($c == $level + 1) {
     $level++;
     $p[] = [$i]; 
     $p = &$p[count($p)-1];
     continue;
  }  
  // any level less then achived before
  if ($c < $level) {  
     $p = &$result;
     $level = $c;
     while($c--)
        $p = &$p[count($p)-1];
     $p[] = $i;
     continue;
  }
  die("I can't process this input string"); 
}
print_r($result);
```

[working demo](https://eval.in/561395)

Comment: i did not see your comment. But i think that main idea of the code not a way to explode the string (it can be done another) but using pointer to make array. Don't you think so?

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck!